# Getting data of a facebook page one needs to login to see

Tags: php, javascript, facebook, screen-scraping

I have a facebook page which contains data I want to be copied daily to my computer.

The source code isn't accessible unless I connect to facebook account manually and goto that URL.

How can that be done with PHP so It connects to my account ?

(I can then just save the source code)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can only be done with macro or the facebook API, 
I used macro eventually with autoHotKey.